# NameError in Users#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

customer cannot sign up to my web application.  get error  NameError in Users#new

error message . Showing /Users/neilpatel/Desktop/Rails/sample_app/app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb where line #1 raised:

```
**<% if object.errors.any? %>  <-error**
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and this is the view they should see to add sign up details

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

and this is the code for new sign ups

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <%= render 'fields', f: f %>
      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the new user confirmation code

```
<li>
    <%=link_to user.name, user %>
    <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
    | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete,
                                  data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

trace route

```
Started GET "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-10 20:56:41 +0000
Processing by UsersController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (43.9ms)
  Rendered users/_fields.html.erb (44.8ms)
  Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (47.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 51ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `object' for #<#<Class:0x007fe9aa752d58>:0x007fe9a9fb3b88>):
    1: <% if object.errors.any? %>
    2:   <div id="error_explanation">
    3:     <div class="alert alert-error">
    4:       The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
  app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_shared__error_messages_html_erb__4173887643235544536_70320816602040'
  app/views/users/_fields.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_users__fields_html_erb__1761016343315845667_70320816564760'
  app/views/users/new.html.erb:8:in `block in _app_views_users_new_html_erb___922995521922748898_70320816483500'
  app/views/users/new.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_users_new_html_erb___922995521922748898_70320816483500'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/actionpack-4.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (16.1ms)
```

user.controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: [:destroy, :following, :followers]

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end


  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end


  def edit
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
    #@user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"  
      redirect_to @user      # Handle a successful update.
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end



  def create

   @user = User.new(user_params)
   if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted."
    redirect_to users_url
  end


def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

private

  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Comment: The error clearly states `object` is not defined for your View. Can you show your `new` action in your `UsersController`? You probably meant `@user` depending on the code of your action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first form, you need to assign an object to `object`:

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @user %>

<%= f.label :name %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>

<%= f.label :email %>
<%= f.text_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password" %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

You're actually doing it correctly elsewhere in your code, looks like a simple oversight.